# Do Solr configuration questions belong on DBA?

Tags: discussion

Are questions related to configuring Apache Solr on topic at DBA? By sheer number of questions, I'm uncertain. DBA has 1 question tagged for [solr](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solr), Server Fault has ~150, and Stack Overflow has ~11,000.

While preparing for a production environment, I've had a few questions related to Apache Solr which I eventually figured out the answers to but they were not readily available or apparent through searching:

1. What characters are valid for a core name? (equivalent to an SQL table).

   The answer to this is pretty simple, but it's undocumented.
2. How do you share the core configuration between multiple cores? (equivalent to sharing a table definition between identical table structures, but with different data sets in SQL).

   This has been answered twice on Stack Overflow about specific older versions, but for newer versions there is a built-in feature.

Would these questions be appropriate here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect one of the other two is a better place, particularly Stack Overflow which obviously has a decent number of active users on the tag. According to [the features page](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html) this is exactly the kind of product the NoSQL people would be furious about if we ever even hinted that it is a "database." This is not to say that I (as a moderator) would close questions about Lucene or Solr. But if you are asking if I *encourage* those questions here, I would have to say no, that other more established communities are currently better equipped and more appropriate to handle them. That may change over time.

As for Question #2, I don't think it should be a new question, there should be a new answer on the existing (generic) question where the answer is version-specific. I don't like the habit we've gotten into about "How do I do x?" and it's its own question because the answer is different for a different version. Most people don't even see the version-specific tags.

Comment: Since I know the answers to my questions, I intend to self-answer them. I just want to make sure I am asking and answering on the correct and most appropriate SE site. The divide between the various SE sites is very blurry to me. I also don't want to encourage bad habits by asking on the wrong site which I think happens more so on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @cpburnz Yes, understood, and there are a *lot* of questions that are on topic both here and on Stack Overflow. We tend to try and draw more complex query and internals questions here, letting SO keep basic queries and questions about config. But we don't kick a whole lot of questions away, either.